# jquery check if h2 contains specific text

Tags: php, jquery, data-binding

I have this jquery checking if h2 contains the word Simple but I'm not sure why its not working for me?
Here is my script and here is what im trying to check for.

```
<section class="main">

    <nav>
        <a class="show-menu"><i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i></a>

        <ul>
            <li class="static active"><a href="theme"><?php print _("Themes"); ?></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>


    <div id="themesList" class="image-list" data-bind="foreach: themes">

        <div class="image-item" data-bind="css:{active: ($parent.theme()==id())}">
            <h2 data-bind="text: name"></h2>

            <img data-bind="attr:{'src': 'themes/'+id()+'/logo.png'}">

              <div class="preview-button">


            <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'themes/'+id()+'/logo.png'}" data-lightbox="+id()+" data-title=data-bind="attr: { text: 'name'}">Preview</a>

            </div>
            <div class="secondary inactive-button" data-bind="click: $parent.showApplyDialog"><?php print _("Apply Theme"); ?></div>
            <div class="active-button" data-bind="click: $parent.showResetDialog"><?php print _("Reset Theme"); ?></div>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var $h2 = $('.image-item h2');

if ($h2.text().indexOf('simple') > -1) {
    $h2.hide();
}
</script>
    </div>
    <!-- /.list -->

</section>
<!-- /.main -->
```

The data-bind is what populates the h2

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf()` method to see if a string contains in js. I left out the part with `data-bind` in my demo.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hBd97/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    var $h2 = $('.image-item h2');

    //add this
    console.log($h2);
    console.log('text: ' +  $h2.text());

    if ($h2.text().indexOf('Simple') > -1) {
        $h2.hide();
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: so how would i add the data-bind ? i tried yours and its still not hidding and i appreciate your help so much

Comment: @user3546263 are you using knockout (javascript)?

Comment: Yes... i just wanted it to hide it if the h2 said simple... lol

Comment: @user3546263 it is case sensitive so make sure "Simple" you check for is the same that is actually in the h2.

Comment: i did and its still not... where should i put the script above or below ?

Comment: @user3546263 If the output of the h2 is with a big S then the code above will fail as it's "simple" not "Simple". Also look at my updated answer.

Comment: for some reason its not working :/ i have another question that would help out too and its about data-binding..

Comment: data-title=data-bind="attr: { text: 'name'}"

Comment: @user3546263 does your knockout work? are you sure you have the jquqery file added?

Comment: I updated my answer, add the line and check in the console to see the value

Comment: [prevObject: e.fn.e.init[1], context: document, selector: ".image-item h2", constructor: function, init: function…]
 theme:237
text:

Comment: the text was blank for some reason